# jQuery toggle class of label when radio button is clicked

Tags: jquery, radio-button, label, toggleclass

I have a label surrounding my radio button where the background is supposed to change on :hover and :focus

```
<label for="radio1" class="radio-blur">
<input name="job" id="radio1" value="1" type="radio"> Graphic Design</label>
```

I want to change the class from .radio-blur to .radio-focus

I have

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input:radio').click(function() {
            $(this).parent('label').toggleClass('.radio-focus');
        });  
    });
```

But it doesn't work... please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the dot in the class

```
$(this).parent('label').toggleClass('radio-blur radio-focus');
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexBay/nNHbK/)

Comment: You want to remove .radio-blur as well?

Comment: yea I want to swap classes so that .radio-focus takes the place of .radio-blur

Comment: can we toggle classes with fade effect

Comment: This function let you change the class attribute. Use the fadeIn/Out function just after it.